# Does anyone know where to find cholov yisrael condensed milk?

Tags: product-recommendation, dairy, chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk

Does anyone know what companies make or where to find cholov yisrael condensed milk? I'm having a really hard time finding it, I'm from New York

Answer (score 1):

[condensed milk cholov yisroel](https://bakerschoiceny.com/product/milk-cream/)

[similar link](https://www.mercato.com/item/bakers-choice-sweetened-milk-cream-105-ounces/943375?featuredStoreId=2318&region_id=71008887&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=engine:google%7Ccampaignid:11590164885%7Cadid:478895459662%7Cgclid:Cj0KCQjw1N2TBhCOARIsAGVHQc6xzB1MTRtZ8PILd9Qo2DV0ZCEoVPugQXp8fgICysOXLKwtW72J5MQaAhhCEALw_wcB&gclid=Cj0KCQjw1N2TBhCOARIsAGVHQc6xzB1MTRtZ8PILd9Qo2DV0ZCEoVPugQXp8fgICysOXLKwtW72J5MQaAhhCEALw_wcB)

It seems it is called Baker's Choice (brand) and it is made under New Square Kosher certification (dairy - cholov Yisroel).

In the first link you can actually scroll on the image of their container and see the ingredients and nutritional labeling as well as the image of the New Square cholov Yisroel kashrus certification.

New Square is a township in NY (north of Manhattan) entirely populated and governed by Skvere Chassidic Jews. I believe the links offer the ability to contact the company and distributor for more info and shipping options.

Although it is described as condensed milk cream, it seems to be the same idea as condensed sweetened milk.

I hope this helps.